# Jquery scrollLeft to div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, scroll

please tell me, how I can scroll left to some div like 'scrollTo(#id)'

I mean it is possible to make function like this:

```
$('#some_div').scrollLeftTo('.segment'); ?
```

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Just get the elements offset position from the left and scroll to that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#some_div').animate({scrollLeft:$('.segment').offset().left);
```

Comment: thanks, but how I can make 'Next' button, that each press, scroll #some_div to next .segment?

Comment: $('.next').on('click',function(){
    $('#some_div').animate({scrollLeft:'+=' + $('.segment').offset().left);
})